# WordPress wp-admin in Linux Shared Host is out of reach

Tags: linux, wordpress, cpanel, wp-admin

These days I am facing a weird problem with my wordpress websites on a linux shared host.
I had 6 WordPress websites on my Linux shared host service. As two of them were moved to a new server, I tried to cleanup some mess by deleting some of the cached, temp and log files from different folders such as .trash, .cache, tmp and so on. (I don't remember what files are deleted from which folders exactly).
[image]

After this cleaning, I can see the main page of the websites but all /wp-admin's are out of reach even if I install a fresh WP. 
When I try to access wp-admin I'll get the following error, 
[image]

and after that I can't see the main pages for a few hours! It seems that cPanel is blocking my IP for a while, because my domain.com/cpanel is also not working after I tried domain/wp-admin.

[image]
Unfortunately, the Mesrahosting host provider has a terrible service support and they are not replying my tickets nor Whatsapp messages.

Any idea to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the tmp folder should exist in your cPanel account. If you deleted it you have to create it in /home/cpaneluserame/tmp and it needs to have cpaneluser:cpaneluser ownership and also 755 permissions. That would be a 1st step. Since you are unable to access cPanel then most probably your ip got blocked by the server's firewall or cPhulkd. In most cases the block is just temporary. If you keep trying then depending on the server's firewall configuration and the settings of cPhulkd (that comes with WHM) your blocking time might be increased gradually. Try accessing cPanel from another ip address (use a proxy or VPN service) and see if that works. When you are able to access cPanel be sure to create /tmp folder and then try again and see if that works. If your ip address is permanently blocked then your only chance to unblock it is to request that to your hoster's tech support team.

So if I were you, I would try accessing cPanel from another ip address.

Comment: As you can see on the first picture, the tmp folder is exist.